# Presto Query of array of structs returns individual sttruct elements as columns instead of rows of structs

Tags: presto

Here is sample data and presto query with actual results and desired results.

```
WITH
dataset AS (
  SELECT 
      ARRAY[
        CAST(ROW('Sally', 'engineering') AS ROW(name VARCHAR, department VARCHAR)),
        CAST(ROW('John', 'finance') AS ROW(name VARCHAR, department VARCHAR))
      ] AS users
)
select t.*
from dataset
cross join unnest(users) as t
```

**Output Returned 2 columns**:
name and department and 2 rows.

**Desired output**:
1 column of type struct and 2 rows.

How do i get the desired result in presto? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is SQL standard behavior.

You can get the desired output with

```
SELECT ROW(t.name, t. department)
```

or, by preventing the [`unnest`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) from "unpacking" the rows with a [`transform()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform):

```
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(transform(users, u -> ROW(u)) as t
```

Comment: Thank you Piotr for quick response. unnest transform solution is neat. Appreciate it.